# Implementing alarms and conditions on OPC UA server

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I need to implement Alarms in my OPC UA server, it is very difficult to find information about `opc-ua` alarms and conditions, therefore it would be helpful if we could discuss this topic here. I have a few questions though.

1) Is it mandatory to define "Areas" to enable alarm events?
2) When I define a condition in the address space, do I need to add a reference for the node variable that I need to monitor? 
3) Is there another way to raise an alarm that occurs in another application in the OPS UA server?
4) Is there any example/tutorial that I can look into to learn more?

Comment: Please post a minimal and re-producible code you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already check the OPC UA Specification on Alarms and Conditions:

https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/specifications-unified-architecture/part-9-alarms-and-conditions/

(Freely accessible after registering)

It is very detailed and probably answers most of your questions.

Example code for such an implementation can be found here:
https://github.com/open62541/open62541/blob/master/examples/tutorial_server_alarms_conditions.c

Answer (score 0):

The [iot-edge-opc-plc:AlarmConditionsNodeManager](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-edge-opc-plc/blob/master/src/AlarmCondition/AlarmConditionNodeManager.cs) is a C# OPC UA PLC Simulation that supports Alarms and Conditions and is based on the [OPC Foundation NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua/).

Besides from that:

- I think areas are mandatory
- To raise an Alarm from another Application your OPC UA server

  - need to provide an interface for that
  - monitor an public interface of the other application
- OPC Foundation provides a [Forum](https://opcfoundation.org/forum/) for such discussions
- if the Spec isn’t clear enough, it is the best way to open a [Mantis issue](https://opcfoundation.org/resources/issue-tracking/) that OPC Foundation can improve
- OPC Foundation publishes latest release of spec also as [online reference](https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/docs/Part9/)

  - currently only major version 1.04 without errata but it is a good point to start and don’t require registration